# SWI prolog return true instead of variable

Tags: prolog

here is my code

```
/*facts*/
male(James).
male(Charles).
male(William).
female(Megan).
male(George).
female(Catherine).
female(Diana).
female(Elizabith).
parent(James,Charles).
parent(James,Elizabeth).
parent(Charles,Catherine).
parent(Charles,William).
parent(Charles,Megan).
parent(Elizabeth,Diana).
parent(Diana,George).
/*rules*/
different(X,Y):- X\=Y.
father(X, Y) :-  parent(X,Y), male(X).
mother(X, Y) :- parent(X,Y), female(X).
grandparent(X,Y):- parent(X,F), parent(F,Y).
grandma(X,Y):- parent(X,F), parent(F,Y),female(X).
sister(X,Y):-female(X), parent(F,X), parent(F,Y),different(X,Y) .
brother(X,Y):-male(X), parent(F,X), parent(F,Y),different(X,Y).
aunt(X,Y):-parent(F,Y), sister(X,F), female(X).
uncle(X,Y):-parent(F,Y), brother(X,F), male(X).
```

i write mother(X,Y). expecting return name not true or false .
same with all statements

Answer (score 1):

Your *facts* use variables and not constants. Constants and functors start with a lowercase, so `james`, `charles`, `megan` and `diana`, not <s>`James`</s>, <s>`Charles`</s>, <s>`Megan`</s> and <s>`Diana`</s>:

```
male(james).
male(charles).
male(william).
female(megan).
male(george).
female(catherine).
female(diana).
female(elizabith).
parent(james, charles).
parent(james, elizabeth).
parent(charles, catherine).
parent(charles, william).
parent(charles, megan).
parent(elizabeth, diana).
parent(diana, george).
```